# How to download local image sets to use with Keras?

Tags: python, load, deep-learning, keras

Iam new to keras and after testing some tutorials with mnist images I would like to train with my own data set. The data are .png images of numbers from 0-9. 
I ordered them into 10 classes, each containing 100 .png images of the numbers separately (so one folder for 0, one folder for 1, one folder for 2 etc ..).

now I am wondering how to load the images with python, for keras to use them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Keras’ `ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory()` to generate batches of your image data from your file system that you will then train your model on. Once you have your images organized in the file system, creating `ImageDataGenerator()` would be the next step.

[This video](https://youtu.be/LhEMXbjGV_4) demonstrates how to prep your image data and create your `ImageDataGenerator()`, and then [this video](https://youtu.be/daovGOlMbT4) demonstrates how to train your CNN on the image data.

An example of this would look like

```
train_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(directory=<path_to_image_data>, target_size=(224,224), classes=[‘0’, '1', ‘2’, ‘3’, …, ‘9’], batch_size=10)
```